# Django - revisiting "change password at next login”

Tags: python, django

I apologize, as this has been asked before (https://stackoverflow.com/a/5570717/3529404).  However, I am having trouble with the accepted answer from user Chris Pratt.  The code generally works - I am able to force password reset.  However, where I am having trouble is trying to ensure that the new password is different than the old password.  As the code is currently written, the same password is allowed.

From Chris's answer:

```
def password_change_signal(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=instance.username)
        if not user.password == instance.password:
          profile = user.get_profile()
          profile.force_password_change = False
          profile.save()
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        pass
```

It seems as this should be checked in the line:

```
if not user.password == instance.password:
```

However, when I print user.password and instance.password (despite entering in the same password in both fields), the hashed value is not equal.  Oddly enough, if I keep changing the password, the value that is printed for instance.password becomes the value for user.password on the next change.

Basically, all I want to do is use the code from the previous linked answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/5570717/3529404), but enforce that the new password is different than the old password.

Thank you!!

**UPDATE!**

As discussed in the comments, I think my main area of frustration at the moment is not understanding exactly how user/instance differ.  In particular, when print both user and instance passwords (see below), the hashed values are different even though the same password has been entered in each.

My code is slightly different than @Chris Pratt's because I am not using the depreciated user profile commands.  Hopefully I didn't leave anything out!

webapp/models.py

```
class UserAdditional(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    force_password_change = models.BooleanField(default=True)

def create_user_additional_signal(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserAdditional.objects.create(user=instance)

def password_change_signal(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=instance.username)
        # these hashed values differ, even when the instance password entered is the same as the stored user password
        print user.password
        print instance.password
        if not user.password == instance.password:
            useradditional_obj = UserAdditional.objects.get(user=user)
            useradditional_obj.force_password_change = False
            useradditional_obj.save()
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        pass

signals.pre_save.connect(password_change_signal, sender=User, dispatch_uid='webapp.models')

signals.post_save.connect(create_user_additional_signal, sender=User, dispatch_uid='webapp.models')
```

webapp/middleware.py

```
class PasswordChangeMiddleware:
    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated() and not re.match(r'^/password_change/?', request.path) \
            and not re.match(r'^/logout/?', request.path):
            useradditional_obj = UserAdditional.objects.get(user=request.user)
            if useradditional_obj.force_password_change:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/password_change/')
```

webapp/forms.py --- for password requirement enforcing

```
class ValidatingPasswordForm(object):
    MIN_LENGTH = 8

    def clean_new_password1(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('new_password1')

        # At least MIN_LENGTH long
        if len(password1) < self.MIN_LENGTH:
            raise forms.ValidationError("The new password must be at least %d characters long." % self.MIN_LENGTH)

        # check numbers and special characters
        nums = len(set(re.findall(r'[0-9]',password1)))
        symb = len(set(re.findall(r'[~!@#$%^&\*()_+=-`]',password1)))

        if nums <= 0 or symb <= 0:
            raise forms.ValidationError("The new password must contain at least one number and one special character [~!@#$%^&\*()_+=-`]")

        return password1

class ValidatingPasswordChangeForm(ValidatingPasswordForm, auth.forms.PasswordChangeForm):
    pass

class ValidatingSetPasswordForm(ValidatingPasswordForm, auth.forms.SetPasswordForm):
    pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally a good practice to require an authenticated user provide the current password when changing passwords. This protects against the case, even if unlikely, that a logged in user leaves the workstation with an active session and some "evil" user attempts to hijack their account by changing the password.

By requiring the user to enter both the old and new passwords you can also prevent password re-use both on the client and server side. This allows for increased usability for your users since you can warn them and disable submission of the form using JavaScript. By capturing the old and new passwords, you can pass both to the server and verify against re-use similar to the answer provided by warath-coder.

### Update

As you've mentioned Django saved the hashes and not the actual passwords, and as a further protection the passwords are salted, see the Django docs on [how passwords are stored](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/passwords/#how-django-stores-passwords). Because of this, you will not be able to simply compare the hashes. You can test that the old and new passwords match in the `clean_new_password1` method of your form using the form data prior to the User object being updated. This can be done by simple comparison or by trying to authenticate with the old password as warath-coder has described.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation!  I agree with your points.  I think I am making a mistake somewhere trying to accessing all of the input (old_password, new_password1) from the default django form.  I'll keep at it and figure out where I am messing up.

I tried comparing instance.password and user.password but cannot figure out why I am getting different hashed values even though they are the same password being entered in.

Comment: Of course, apologies for my delay.  I'll update the question above with more details.

Comment: Thanks @Fiver.  I feel like an idiot, but I just cannot get access to my `old_password` within the `clean_new_password1` method.  If I type:
`oldpass = self.cleaned_data.get('old_password')` I get a result of `None`
 
I've got to be missing something obvious....

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
def password_change_signal(sender, instance, **kwargs):
try:
    user = authenticate(username=instance.username, password=instance.password)
    if user is None:  # means auth failed, which means password is not the same as the current password.
        user = User.objects.get(username=instance.username)
        user.set_password(instance.password)
        user.save()
        profile = user.get_profile()
        profile.force_password_change = False
        profile.save()
except User.DoesNotExist:
    pass
```

basically i try to authenticate the user with the password they supply, and it should fail if the new password is different than the current.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, very helpful.

I think I am having a more fundamental issue trying to compare instance.password and user.password but cannot figure out why I am getting different hashed values even though they are the same password being entered in.  I'll have to dive deeper into this.

Comment: Thanks @warath-coder.  Unfortunately my authenticate appears to be failing despite using the same password for both old and new.  I think this is still an issue with me not using instance properly....

Code has been updated above.