# Django Database and User Authentication

Tags: django, authentication, psql

Novice Programmer Here. I want to create a login system with hundreds of users. Initially, I am given a some database information about these users in the format:

```
student#| first_name | last_name | student_ID |
--------|------------|-----------|------------|
10001   | Bob        | Jones     | Bob100     |
10002   | Andy       | Guo       | And101     |
10003   | Andy       | Sir       | And102     |
10004   | Bob        | Jones     | Bob101     |
```

The first and last names can be the same but student# and student_ID# will always be unique.
Therefore, I want the **student_ID** to be the **username** and **student#** to be the **password**. After reading some tutorials I have implemented a very basic login system where I have to manually create the user:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Then I use the following code to authenticate the user:

```
def auth_view(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username', '')
    password = request.POST.get('password', '')
    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/loggedin')
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/invalid')
```

So I was thinking of a couple of options and I wanted to ask your opinions:

1. Create a script that parses through the database for student# and student_ID and create the users.
2. Whenever the students login, check the username(student_ID) and password(password) to see if they match. (Essentially writing my own authentication code?)

I'm not sure if I am going about this in the right direction. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Use django default authentication mechanism . refer this documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/ 

And I suggest you to encrypt and store password using hashing technique instead of storing it as raw text/

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend against creating a system where the users password is the student ID. Instead I would recommend allowing users to create passwords and use your list of names and ID’s to verify and match them as part of registration.

Alternatively, you can pre-populate a list of users and set the password using `set_password(student ID)` and require the user to change their password on [their first logon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28004657/django-revisiting-change-password-at-next-login) .

The main take away is that Django already has a really good authentication system that allows users to set secure passwords and hashes them correctly using bcrypt that is just as easy to implement. It is really bad juju to roll your own authentication unless you have a very good reason to do so.