# Require the user to change their password on first login?

Tags: python, django

I would like to force the user to change their password on first login. Can I do this with the default django authentication system?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093593/is-it-possible-to-implement-a-change-password-at-next-logon-type-feature-in-th

Answer (score 2):

In short, yes.

You need to know which users need to change their password. If you don't want to use a custom User model, I would recommend having another model to store the users that need to change their password. You would add the users to this table upon user registration/creation.

Then you could write a very simple middleware to check the current logged user (place it after AuthenticationMiddleware in your settings.py). If the user is flagged as requiring a password change, you could force a HttpResponse (in the middleware) to a custom view with a PasswordChangeForm (which comes out of the box in Django, in django.contrib.auth.forms.PasswordChangeForm), after which you could remove the flag to the user, and redirect them to the home page.

Comment: I can take a simple example of what explains, use django 1.7, yes I use a custom User model

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I understood everything explained to me, I just have a question .As I know if the User must change name_ ?, for example with a bool attribute? And _ default is true?

Comment: If you are using a custom user model, then you only need a BooleanField to store whether or not a password change is required. Same logic as explained before, but with only one model involved now. `user_must_change_password = models.BooleanField(..., default=True)`